# .htaccess RewriteRule so user views example.com/folder but is served example.com/f1/f2/f3/folder/index.php

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure how to make a `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` so a visitor views `example.com/folder`

but is served

`example.com/f1/f2/f3/folder/index.php`

where `f1/...` is just an arbitrary line of folders.

I have kicked `mod_rewrite` a little, and got some really weird results, none I was going for though.

Comment: To be more specific, I have a site framework that is buried several folders deep, so the root of the site starts as say site.com/folder1/folder2/index.php... I want that to be equivalent to site.com.  Also, I need it so that site.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php will be seen as site.com/folder3

I hope that is more clear.

Comment: So this will redirect the root, but not anything else: Rewriterule ^$ nest/site/$1 [L].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. This, however, might solve your problem. Basically it translates any query for `/folder`, `/folder/` or `/folder/...` to `/f1/f2/f3/folder/...`:

```
RewriteRule ^folder(/.*)?$ f1/f2/f3/folder$1
```

---

**EDIT**
*If* you don't care about anything after `site.com/folder`, this should suffice:

```
RewriteRule ^folder$ f1/f2/f3/folder/index.php
```

---

**EDIT #2**
Rewriting the root (according to comment by OP):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder1/folder2/$1 [QSA]
```

There may be other (better?) ways to translate the root, though.

[Docs are available](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) on the `QSA` directive.

Comment: Your first pattern will also allow `folderfoobar`.

Comment: I am able to get the first approach to work, but it still requires I have the root 1 folder deep, so the root index ends up at site.com/folder/index.php... Tried edit 2, but that threw 500 Internal Server Error.   I have the .htaccess file in the root of the subdomain this lives in, and do not have any .htacess files below it.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but this works: 

Rewriterule ^folder/(.*)$ folder1/folder2/$1

This throws a 500 internal server error: 

Rewriterule ^(.*)$ folder1/folder2/$1

as does this:

Rewriterule ^(.*)$ folder1/folder2/$1 [QSA]

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` located?